# GetJSON check for Empty data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am using MVC c# i have a object with

```
public class Person
{
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }

}
```

i have a code that retruns JSON object for this object like this

```
return Json(personCodeStore.GetPersonCodes(id).Select(x=>new {text =x.Code, value =x.TypeId}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

how do i add a Indicator to my JSON return data, so that i can check for empty data

```
$.getJSON('../PersonList?id=1', function (data) {
if (data==????)
{
alert("has data");
}
else
{
alert("is Empty");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just check for a property you know a Person object would have? Something like this:

```
if (data.Id) {
  // We got back something with an Id property... probably a Person
} else {
  // What else could we get back?!?
}
```

Comment: Well then what data do you expect to get back? what properties does the data have that you CAN check?

Comment: I had to do 
if (data[0].Id) {
  // We got back something with an Id property... probably a Person
} else {
  // What else could we get back?!?
}

Comment: Aaah... it was an array of objects. Glad you figured it out.